# Format a complex mixture of hashes and array and put out an end result as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After a lot of fixing an old app, i am now left with this

```
@products = {:parent_products=>[["Product title", "Product body 1", "3", "user1"], ["Product title 2", "Product body 2", "5", "user_2"]], :child_products=>[["making a reply", "user_2", "3", "4"], ["yes i read it", "user_5", "5", "6"], ["me too indeed. hurray", "user_1", "4", "7"], ["great to see this", "user_7", "3", "8"]]}
```

Now what I cant figure out how to do is -

- Format `@products[:child_products]` in such a way that, if lets say `@products[:child_products][2][2]` includes in any of the elements in any of the elements with the inner index being `[3]` it should be appended to that array's last index, as the array itself.

So for example, from the above given hash we can see that

value of `@products[:child_products][2][2]` does have one another like it, at `@products[:child_products][0][3]` (which is the integer 4). Since it is being met `true` the new array should now look like

```
["making a reply","user_2", "3", "4", ["me too indeed. hurray","user_1", "4", "7"]]
```

**Now note:** the above is just an example. In other words inside the `@products[:child_products]` a search should made in a search a way that it looks

```
@products[:child_products][<any index>][2] inside @products[:child_products][<any index>][3]
```

Hope I am making sense so far.

- Moving on, if the condition is not met or even met (as mentioned in the first point) and the arrays inside `@products[:child_products]` have been rearranged, it should now run another logic where

`@products[:child_products][<any index>][2] should look for @product[:parent_products][<any index>][2]`

And once the condition is met it should append that entire array into the array of `@product[:parent_products]`

So for example `@product[:child_products][1][2]` matches `@product[:parent_products][1][2]` (which is 5) then the new array set (of the respective index position) inside `@product[:parent_products]` should look like

```
["Product title 2", "Product body 2", "5", "user_2",["yes i read it", "user_5", "5", "6"]]
```

Thats all.

I tried my best to make sure I am stating the output clear. If you have any questions please ask.

---

**UPDATE: I see that above is creating confusion. So here is the quick glance on what i have and what i want**

What I have

```
@products = {:parent_products=>[["Product title", "Product body 1", "3", "user1"], ["Product title 2", "Product body 2", "5", "user_2"]], :child_products=>[["making a reply", "user_2", "3", "4"], ["yes i read it", "user_5", "5", "6"], ["me too indeed. hurray", "user_1", "4", "7"], ["great to see this", "user_7", "3", "8"]]}
```

And the final output I want is an array with the formatted data

```
[["Product title", "Product body 1", "3", "user1", ["making a reply", "user_2", "3", "4", ["me too indeed. hurray", "user_1", "4", "7"]], ["great to see this", "user_7", "3", "8"] ], ["Product title 2", "Product body 2", "5", "user_2", ["yes i read it", "user_5", "5", "6"]]]
```

Thanks

Comment: This creating confusions... rather just mention what you have and what you want based on what in simple.. with small examples..

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look and let me know if its still not clear. Thanks.

Comment: What have you got/tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@products = {:parent_products=>[["Product title", "Product body 1", "3", "user_1"], ["Product title 2", "Product body 2", "5", "user_2"]],
:child_products=>[["making a reply", "user_2", "3", "4"], ["yes i read it", "user_5", "5", "6"],
["me too indeed. hurray", "user_1", "4", "7"], ["great to see this", "user_7", "3", "8"]]}


arr = @products[:parent_products].flat_map do |i|  
  i << @products[:child_products].select{|j| j.any? {|m| m == i[-1] || m == i[-2]}}
end

arr 
# => ["Product title",
#     "Product body 1",
#     "3",
#     "user_1",
#     [["making a reply", "user_2", "3", "4"],
#      ["me too indeed. hurray", "user_1", "4", "7"],
#      ["great to see this", "user_7", "3", "8"]],
#     "Product title 2",
#     "Product body 2",
#     "5",
#     "user_2",
#     [["making a reply", "user_2", "3", "4"],
#      ["yes i read it", "user_5", "5", "6"]]]
```

Comment: @psharma You are welcome.. I just took a guess from the output and input in your last update. But really don't understand what you meant inside the long text.. :) anyway if it is the one you were looking for,and if it helps you,then I am happy.  :)

Comment: oh i tried this in the console. but what happens now is there is duplication of data, maybe its because u are using flat_map?

Comment: in consolve its showing fine but if i put this in the rails app the entire output seems put be messed up

Comment: @psharma Ok.. I don't have any idea about rails.. sorry :(

Comment: I just realized i made a mistake into the generation of the hash. will you be willing to do it again, if i paste the new hash? Extremely sorry.

Comment: @psharma no problem,but post another question please... :)

Comment: i have added new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496510/print-out-an-array-out-of-a-complex-mixture-of-hashes-and-arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product
  attr_reader :description, :body, :id, :child_id

  def initialize description, body, id, child_id
    @description, @body, @id, @child_id = description, body, id, child_id
    @children = []
  end

  def append child
    @children << child
  end

  def accepts? child
    child.id == self.id
  end

  def to_a
    [description, body, id, child_id] + @children.map(&:to_a)
  end
end

class ChildProduct < Product
  def accepts? child
    self.child_id == child.id
  end
end

class ProductTransformer
  def initialize products
    @products = products
  end

  def transform
    parents  = @products[:parent_products].map{|e| Product.new *e}
    children = @products[:child_products].map{|e| ChildProduct.new *e}
    children.each do |child|
      p = parents.detect{|parent| parent.accepts? child}
      p.append child if p
      children.each do |another|
        next if another === child
        child.append another if child.accepts?(another)
      end
    end
    parents.map(&:to_a)
  end
end

products = {
  :parent_products=>[
    ["Product title",   "Product body 1", "3", "user1"],
    ["Product title 2", "Product body 2", "5", "user_2"]],
  :child_products=>[
    ["making a reply",        "user_2", "3", "4"], 
    ["yes i read it",         "user_5", "5", "6"], 
    ["me too indeed. hurray", "user_1", "4", "7"], 
    ["great to see this",     "user_7", "3", "8"]]
}
ProductTransformer.new(products).transform
```